# What are the downsides of using euclidean distance for hierarchical clustering of a correlation matrix?

Tags: r, correlation, distance, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find any answers discussing this specific question.

I am lacking some notion on clustering using euclidean vs correlation distance, when applied to a correlation matrix.

Say I have N samples, for which I calculated the correlations between them, yielding an NxN correlation matrix. I now wish to, using hierarchical clustering, obtain a dendrogramme to group said samples.

I understand that correlation distances exist, specifically that one can use 1-cor(X,Y) or 1-abs(cor(X,Y)) as a way to group the samples by their similarity, with the second case considering positive and negative correlations as "equally similar" (i.e. distance = 0 for cor = 1 and cor = -1). So, clustering the correlations based on these distances will result in the samples clustering based on their similarity given their correlation.

What I am lacking the intuition for is **what would mean if we instead used euclidean distance to hierarchically cluster the correlations**, why would that be wrong compared to using correlation distance, and if that would be a sensible way of clustering this sort of data.

EDIT: example R code to illustrate my question

```
# prepare data
data(iris)
rev_iris = rev(iris[,1:4]) # to have negative correlations
colnames(rev_iris) = rev(colnames(rev_iris))
dat = rbind(iris[,1:4], rev_iris)
rownames(dat) = paste0("p", 1:nrow(dat))
## labels
annot = rbind(iris[,5,drop=F], iris[,5,drop=F])
rownames(annot) = rownames(dat)

# correlation
cor_iris = cor(t(dat), method = "pearson")

# Comparing clustering of correlations based on two types of distance:
## plot heatmap with correlation (default - euclidean)
pheatmap::pheatmap(cor_iris, annotation_row = annot)
## plot heatmapwith correlation (correlation distance)
pheatmap::pheatmap(cor_iris, annotation_row = annot, 
                   clustering_distance_rows = as.dist(1-cor_iris),
                   clustering_distance_cols = as.dist(1-cor_iris))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV, Tomás. The answer depends on the magnitudes of the correlations.  When those are all small, or ranged very narrowly relative to their mean, the Euclidean distance can be a decent second-order approximation to a more appropriate distance.  Otherwise, the two distances can give very different results and you should be wary of using the Euclidean distance in this application.  What a "sensible way" might be ought to depend on these factors as well as on why you are clustering and how you hope to interpret the results.  Could you elaborate in an edit to your post?

Comment: hi @whuber! thanks for replying! I included an example that I hope illustrated my dillema. But going from your comment, what I'm trying to understand is why we "should be wary of using the Euclidean distance" when clustering correlations, and why is that worse than using correlation-based distances (which truth be told I find more intuitive)

Comment: do you measure the distance between correlation matrices? if you do, then how?

Comment: @Aksakal no, in this case, I'd measure the distances between samples, based on their correlation with other samples. this would be measured either by Euclidean distance, or by correlation distance. and while I understand the reasoning behind using correlation distance (more correlated samples are considered closer), what I'm trying to understand is why we shouldn't be using euclidean distance

Comment: @tomsgoms Euclidian distance cannot be inherently wrong. imagine your sample was the coordinate of a point in Euclidian space, then Euclidian distance would be the most appropriate. there must be a reason for using a particular distance